# Can I edit iOS Shortcuts in a text editor (or something) on my Mac?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

Is it possible to create or edit iOS Shortcuts using something other than an iOS device?

I've created a shortcut that rolls on a table and provides the output of that roll.  Entering in 100 entries on my iPhone is rather painful, especially as there are a dozen or so tables I'd like to program.  If I could edit the shortcut's definition as JSON, XML, or whatever on my Mac and then import it back into the Shortcuts app, that would be wonderful.  Is this possible?

I've never used XCode but is that a possibility if text editing is not?

I have the complete list of table entries in plain text format already, if there is some other approach rather than retyping all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, unless you want to edit it in a `plist` format as states by @grg, but you could use an application called [ScPL](https://docs.scpl.dev/gettingstarted.html) to write your shortcuts, then convert it to a `.shortcut` file and import it. There is also [Shortcutor](https://shortcutor.com/), however it is a paid app.

Comment: I believe neither ScPL nor Shortcutor supports Shortcuts after iOS14 it so. The new go-to app seems to be Jellycut.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with macOS Monterey, you can edit most shortcuts on macOS with the companion app. Monterey is expected later this month/year.

Not all shortcuts can be edited - actions that are not supported on Mac (such as controlling cellular service) will not be editable, but the shortcut overall will be.

[image: Shortcuts on Monterey]

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts are just property list files. You can edit these in Xcode, but there's no documentation of course! Rename the file extension to .plist and open with Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since Apple introduced some changes in the Shortcuts format they no longer seem to be `plist` files so that neither ScPL nor Shortcutor work with these.

The new go-to app for editing shortcuts seems to be [Jellycuts](https://jellycuts.com/).